# Young weeping silver birch heavy on one side

Tags: pruning, growth

[image]

My young weeping silver birch arrived with most of its branches on the left side.  Maybe a silly question but will branches grow on right as it grows in height or is there something I could do to help it along?

Answer (score 1):

It will improve as it ages. You can help by turning the less leafy side towards the sun.